# Help with a jQuery Carousel

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a problem where the generated set of divs (from an Eventbrite API call) are not being hit by the jQuery call. See the attached code:

```
//* Add widget support for homepage. If no widgets active, display the default loop.
add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'elegance_home_genesis_meta' );
function elegance_home_genesis_meta() {


        // Force content-sidebar layout setting
        add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );

        // Add elegance-home body class
        add_filter( 'body_class', 'elegance_body_class' );
        function elegance_body_class( $classes ) {

            $classes[] = 'elegance-home';
            return $classes;

        }

        // Remove the default Genesis loop
        remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

        // Add homepage widgets
        add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'elegance_homepage_top_widgets' );
        add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'elegance_homepage_bottom_widgets' );


}

function elegance_homepage_top_widgets() {

?>

<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizers/12073337884/events/?token=ZMDFKJWCHAMX5WFVPBAJ",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }

  jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);

for ( i = 0; i <= data.pagination.object_count; i++) { 

    var content = '<div class="event ' + data.events[i].id + '"><h3>' + data.events[i].name.text + '</h3><br /><a target="_blank" class="button" href="' + data.events[i].url + '">Sign Up Here</a></div>';
   jQuery("#eventbrite-events").append(content);
}

  });
</script>
<div class="home-top widget-area"><div class="wrap">
<div id="eventbrite-events"></div>
</div></div> 

<?php

}

function elegance_homepage_bottom_widgets() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'home-middle', array(
        'before' => '<div class="home-middle widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );


    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'cta-widget' ) ) {

        echo '<div class="cta-widget">';

        genesis_widget_area( 'cta-widget', array(
            'before' => '<div class="cta widget-area">',
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );

        echo '</div>';

    }

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home-bottom' ) ) {

        echo '<div class="home-bottom-full">';

        genesis_widget_area( 'home-bottom', array(
            'before' => '<div class="home-bottom widget-area">',
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );

        echo '</div>';

    }

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hp_elegance_enqueue_scripts_styles' );
function hp_elegance_enqueue_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylecss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylethemecss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'initslick', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/init-slick.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );

}

genesis();
```

I need the generated divs (there are seven of them) to be the ones caught by the Slick carousel. If I do it manually, it works, but I think the order of operations is wrong. I need the Carousel script to run after the divs are generated.

Comment: Hello joe, have you tried to initiate the carousel manually using `$('.your-class').slick();` after the page is loaded?

Comment: I've never actually done that. Would I just attach it to a button? Looking at the console, the working carousel makes all of the Divs one big Div under a generated one. In unworking one, it just adds it above the others. How should I manually start it?

Answer (score 0):

To initiate slick carousel, you need to add the below script in your theme's footer or header (or anywhere else that is loaded with the page) :

```
<script defer type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){$('.myDIV').slick({autoplay:true});});
</script>
```

Remember the change `myDIV` to the class name of a division which is holding subdivisons (parent DIV containing the slides).

Comment: No dice. How is adding that any different than what I did. I was already calling slick.